# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies

Tags: reference, .net-assembly, .net-framework-version

The web application is working fine in my VS2010, but when I hosted it on server it shows error below

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Find in your web.config <dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers"... and try to delete it. if it's work, need to check necessary .NET Framework libararies and  their version.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as MVC has not been installed on the server. 
 and The dll is missing in the published (deployed environment). That is the reason why it is working in the local.

Solution - Copy reference to local

1. Right click on reference System.Web.Helpers and select Properties
2. Change Copy Local to true.
3. Build Solution
4. Re-dploy solution

Comment: System.Web.Helpers doesn't come with .net 3.5?

Comment: i dont know weather it comes or not. but if you put this dll in your bin and then try,i hope it will work

Comment: I already had it in Bin folder. I just change 3.5 to 4.0 in my IIS's pool application. Now it is working fine.